# Output from Studio Flow via API not being sent to website callback

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We are trying to implement a chatbot on our website.

My code successfully triggers the Flow. The Conversations log on Twilio shows that my code sent a message of "Hi" and the Flow triggered and sent the expected greeting.

The problem is that I'm not seeing anyplace where the Flow output is being sent to my website callback and so I'm not able to output the Flow messages to my website user.

When the Flow sends a message, where is the configuration that makes a callback to my website so I can output the message to the user?

onMessageAdded DOES get called on my website callback, but only for messages sent by the website code - not the Flow.

At this point I think the problem is a Twilio configuration for Conversations, Messages or the Flow, but it could be a configuration problem in my code.

Here is my rough initial code:

```
        TwilioClient.Init(_twilioAccountSid, _twilioAuthToken);

        //
        // Create Conversation
        var conversation = ConversationResource.Create(
            friendlyName: "Test conversation",
            messagingServiceSid: _twilioMessagingServiceSid,
            attributes: null,
            xTwilioWebhookEnabled: ConversationResource.WebhookEnabledTypeEnum.True
        );
        _log.Info("Conversation.Create: " + conversation.Sid);

        //
        // Attach Flow to Conversation
        var webhook = WebhookResource.Create(
            configurationMethod: WebhookResource.MethodEnum.Post,
            configurationFlowSid: _twilioStudioFlowSid,
            target: WebhookResource.TargetEnum.Studio,
            configurationFilters: new List<string> {
                "onMessageAdded", 
                "onMessageUpdated", 
                "onMessageRemoved", 
                "onConversationUpdated", 
                "onConversationRemoved", 
                "onParticipantAdded", 
                "onParticipantUpdated", 
                "onParticipantRemoved"
            },
            pathConversationSid: conversation.Sid
        );
        _log.Info("WebhookResource.Create: " + webhook.Sid);

        //
        // Create a Participant
        var participant = ParticipantResource.Create(
            identity: _identity,
            pathConversationSid: conversation.Sid
        );
        _log.Info("Participant.Create: " + participant.Sid);

        //
        // Send Message
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            author: _identity,
            body: "Hi!",
            xTwilioWebhookEnabled: MessageResource.WebhookEnabledTypeEnum.True,
            pathConversationSid: conversation.Sid
        );
        _log.Info("Message.Create: " + message.Sid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you decided to not use the Twilio Conversations SDK for JavaScript?

The architecture you are using may require this additional configuration.

[Triggering Webhooks for REST API Events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/conversations-webhooks#triggering-webhooks-for-rest-api-events)

Upon configuration, only actions from SDK-driven clients (like mobile phones or browsers) or SMS-based Participants will cause webhooks without further action on your part. This includes both Service-level webhooks and Conversation-Scoped Webhooks. This is a default behavior to help avoid infinite feedback loops.

Your Post-Event Webhook target, however, may be an important tool for archiving. In this case, you may also want to enable webhook "echoes" from actions you take on the REST API. To do so, you can add a header X-Twilio-Webhook-Enabled=true to any such request. Requests bearing this header will yield webhooks to the configured Post-Event webhook target.

[Troubleshooting Webhook Delivery for Conversations or Chat](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403669397019-Troubleshooting-Webhook-Delivery-for-Conversations-or-Chat)

I don’t think there is a way to set this header when using [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply) widgets.

Comment: I don't think Twilio has any demos for a single participant and a Studio Flow for a website. They all use SMS or the Programmable Chat. Right now I just want to see a Chatbot (Flow) working on a website. I don't think Twilio has any demos or example code.

Comment: Twilio Flex does exactly that using Twilio Conversations, https://github.com/twilio/twilio-webchat-react-app and https://www.twilio.com/blog/flex-dialogflow-cx-digital

Comment: I'd be increasing monthly cost by using Flex. It isn't free... from what I could see, Flex is over $100/month and for a simple unattended chatbot - it's too pricy for my client.

Comment: How do I add the header and where should I be concentrating? My code or Twilio configurations? My Webhooks are being called for the code above. I see in the Webhook where `body` contains the `Hi` message I created. I can also see that the Flow got triggered and sent the intended message to the conversation - but I don't have any way (in my app) to know when/what the Flow has output. Do you know where/how I should be sending the header?

Comment: You don't need to use Flex, it just shows a use case of using Twilio Conversations as a chat widget for a website. Flex just wraps a contact center around that, for human escalation and proper agent assignment.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the Conversations SDK on your front end?

Comment: I just wanted to see how to make things work. I'm more familiar in C# than React JS and wanted to eliminate as much guesswork as possible. I've ran some of the demo apps. None of them show a website chatbot. I think I'm in better shape to modify one them now. Do you know one that fits best with my use case?